# Org-mode: Exclude specific headlines from TOC when exporting

Tags: org-mode, org-export

**Q:** How can I tell `org-mode` to exclude specific headlines from the table of contents when exporting?

For example, exporting

```
* Headline 1: Put me in TOC
* Headline 2: Put me in TOC
* Headline 3: DO NOT put me in TOC
```

to HTML produces

```
...
<div id="text-table-of-contents">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#sec-1">1. Headline 1: Put me in TOC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec-2">2. Headline 2: Put me in TOC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec-3">3. Headline 3: DO NOT put me in TOC</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
```

but I want it to produce

```
...
<div id="text-table-of-contents">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#sec-1">1. Headline 1: Put me in TOC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec-2">2. Headline 2: Put me in TOC</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
```

The [Table of contents](http://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-contents.html) section of the `org-mode` manual doesn't have any information on this.

Also, I know that I can keep `org-mode` from exporting headlines by setting the `COMMENT` keyword via <kbd>C-c ;</kbd> (`org-toggle-comment`) or by tagging them with `:noexport:`. While this does keep affected headlines from showing up in the TOC, it also causes their contents to be omitted from the resulting document, which is not what I want.

Comment: This isn't the answer you're looking for, but just as a note of another dead-end: `EXPORT_OPTIONS: toc:nil` *almost* does what you want, but only when you export only just the subtree.  To clarify, do you want the section to still be numbered, or do you want something akin to LaTeX's `\section*`?

Comment: @SeanAllred I'd like the section to still be numbered. More generally, I don't want to change anything about the way individual sections are exported. I just don't want some of them to show up in the TOC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note** that as of 2014-10-03 20:06:34 (GMT) check of UNNUMBERED is [built-in already](https://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-Contents.html)

Org uses `org-export-collect-headlines` to collect headlines that should be in the TOC. This function already includes *two* criteria for excluding headlines: the headline depth and whether it is a "footnote section" (*), so it is easy to add another one.

See the modified version of `org-export-collect-headlines` below. This version makes it possible to prevent a headline from showing up in the TOC by setting the `NOTOC` property.

```
* Section 1: shows up in the TOC

* Section 2: modified Org code (not in the TOC)
  :PROPERTIES:
  :NOTOC:    t
  :END:

  This is the modified =org-export-collect-headlines=:

  #+BEGIN_SRC elisp
  (defun org-export-collect-headlines (info &optional n)
    "Collect headlines in order to build a table of contents. [...]

  Return a list of all exportable headlines as parsed elements.
  Footnote sections, if any, will be ignored."
    (let ((limit (plist-get info :headline-levels)))
      (setq n (if (wholenump n) (min n limit) limit))
      (org-element-map (plist-get info :parse-tree) 'headline
        #'(lambda (headline)
            (unless (or (org-element-property :NOTOC headline)               ; new condition
                        (org-element-property :footnote-section-p headline)) ; old condition
              (let ((level (org-export-get-relative-level headline info)))
                (and (<= level n) headline))))
        info)))
  #+END_SRC

** Sub-section
   This shows up in the TOC: property inheritance is off by default.
```

(*) I don't know what "footnote sections" are, though.

This works for export backends that build the TOC manually. LaTeX, Beamer, and Texinfo backends don't.

By adding this advice to `org-export-numbered-headline-p` one can make headlines with the `UNNUMBERED` property export as `\section*{...}`, excluding them from TOC when exporting to  LaTeX and Beamer:

```
(advice-add 'org-export-numbered-headline-p :around
            (lambda (orig headline info)
              (and (funcall orig headline info)
                   (not (org-element-property :UNNUMBERED headline)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for HTML exports. I actually also need this to work for LaTeX/Beamer; I didn't mention this initially because I assumed that there had to be a generic solution that would work for all (or at least most) export back-ends... Do you have any idea how to tackle this issue for LaTeX export? Comparing `.html` and `.tex` files that `org-mode` produces when exporting, the main problem seems to be that `org-mode` builds the TOC manually for HTML, but simply dumps a generic `\tableofcontents` into the `.tex` file.

Comment: @itsjeyd: I don't think a generic solution is possible: as you said, LaTeX (and beamer, and Texinfo) export backends use native commands to build TOC while other backends build TOC manually. It *is* possible to [exclude a section from TOC in LaTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex), but I haven't found a solution that is accepted by the community as the *right one*. Using the idea I linked to in `org-mode` export code would require major changes to `org-latex-headline`. As for implementing this in the Texinfo backed, I even don't know where to start.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for for following up. For Beamer, I think I'll just resort to [making the sections I don't want to show up in the TOC unnumbered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127287/12100). Case closed. :)

Comment: @itsjeyd: You can modify `org-export-numbered-headline-p` to get this behavior almost automatically -- if turning it into a unnumbered section *is* an option, that is. I can elaborate if you're interested.

Comment: Please do - always interested in simplifying solutions!

Comment: @itsjeyd: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Very nice. This solution is a lot cleaner than the one I linked to in my comment. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: How one would test property for entire lineage/parents for latex case? Apparently parent can be unnumbered but children will. I tried setting `org-use-property-inheritance` to `t` but it didn't help.

Comment: It looks like check for `:UNNUMBERED` is already in org-export-numbered-headline-p so there is no special advising is necessary! However it does not work for buffer level properties but subheadings. Oh well.

Comment: @mlt: Thanks for pointing this out! I should probably update this answer. (I might give it a shot sometime tonight. I'll keep you posted.)